# How can I get a tmux session menu from outside a tmux session?

Tags: tmux

I'm trying to build a wrapper for tmux that presents me with a menu of all available sessions instead of creating a new one. However the man page explicitly says that this is not possible (excerpt from the `choose-tree` command):

> This command works only if at least one client is attached.

How could I have a shell function / script to present me with the the menu above, but without goint into tmux first? Or maybe a shortcut to attach and show the chooser in one go?

Answer (score 5):

Probably easiest is to create your own menu and then attach selected session.
Something like following (replace `select` with `dialog`, `zenity` or whatever other menu):

```bash
#!/bin/bash    

select sel in $(tmux ls -F '#S'); do
    break;
done
tmux attach -t "$sel"
```